# How to send a xml request with zeep?

Tags: python, soap, wsdl, zeep

I am struggling to understand how I can request data with python. I used zeep to implement the wsdl file in the code. I think the problem is the body request, that is in xml format. Any help is welcome!

```
from requests import Session
from zeep import Client, Settings
from zeep.transports import Transport

session = Session()
session.verify = ('my_pem_file.pem')
transport = Transport(session=session)
settings = Settings(strict=False, xml_huge_tree=True)
client = Client("my_wdsl_file.xml", transport=transport, settings=settings)


anfrage = '''<item>
               <NAME>VAR_NAME_1</NAME>
               <VALUE>/SIE/PD_VASHU004</VALUE>
            </item>'''

print(client.service.RRW3_GET_QUERY_VIEW_DATA("/SIE/PD_PFI21","",anfrage,"EPIQ_FINANCIALS"))
```

If I run the terminal command `python -wzeep "my_wsdl_file.xml` I get the following method definition:

```
ns0:RRW3_GET_QUERY_VIEW_DATA(I_INFOPROVIDER: ns0:char30, I_QUERY: ns0:char30, I_T_PARAMETER: ns0:RRXW3TQUERY, I_VIEW_ID: ns0:char30)
```

So I placed the char30 provider, the empty char30 query, but I have no idea how to intergrade the xml body request and what the specific format is.

If I run the code snippet like this I get the following exception tree.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\z0044r2t\Desktop\codeSAP.py", line 59, in <module>
    print(client.service.RRW3_GET_QUERY_VIEW_DATA("/SIE/PD_PFI21","",anfrage,"EPIQ_FINANCIALS"))
  File "C:\Users\z0044r2t\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\zeep\proxy.py", line 40, in __call__
    return self._proxy._binding.send(
  File "C:\Users\z0044r2t\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\zeep\wsdl\bindings\soap.py", line 118, in send
    envelope, http_headers = self._create(
  File "C:\Users\z0044r2t\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\zeep\wsdl\bindings\soap.py", line 68, in _create
    serialized = operation_obj.create(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\z0044r2t\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\zeep\wsdl\definitions.py", line 215, in create
    return self.input.serialize(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\z0044r2t\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\zeep\wsdl\messages\soap.py", line 74, in serialize
    self.body.render(body, body_value)
  File "C:\Users\z0044r2t\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\zeep\xsd\elements\element.py", line 231, in render
    self._render_value_item(parent, value, render_path)
  File "C:\Users\z0044r2t\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\zeep\xsd\elements\element.py", line 255, in _render_value_item
    return self.type.render(node, value, None, render_path)
  File "C:\Users\z0044r2t\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\zeep\xsd\types\complex.py", line 279, in render
    element.render(parent, element_value, child_path)
  File "C:\Users\z0044r2t\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\zeep\xsd\elements\indicators.py", line 242, in render
    element.render(parent, element_value, child_path)
  File "C:\Users\z0044r2t\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\zeep\xsd\elements\element.py", line 231, in render
    self._render_value_item(parent, value, render_path)
  File "C:\Users\z0044r2t\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\zeep\xsd\elements\element.py", line 255, in _render_value_item
    return self.type.render(node, value, None, render_path)
  File "C:\Users\z0044r2t\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\zeep\xsd\types\complex.py", line 279, in render
    element.render(parent, element_value, child_path)
  File "C:\Users\z0044r2t\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\zeep\xsd\elements\indicators.py", line 229, in render
    element_value = value[name]
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you able to share the rest of the output from running `python -mzeep`? What is the definition of the type `ns0:RRXW3TQUERY`?